# Подключение к Azure из Android

Tags: azure, android, jdbc, java

Я пытаюсь подключиться с Android к базе SQL Azure с помощью драйвера JDTS 1.2.7.
Код:

```
String connectionString = 
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER.database.windows.net:1433;database=demo;" +
"user=test@SERVER;password=PASSWORD;ssl=require";
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
res=st.executeQuery(sql);
```

Когда пытаюсь соединиться, получаю java.lang.NoClassDefError: com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext exception. Пытался добавить jsse.jar в build path проекта, но приложение просто вылетает, и если даже оно что-то выводит, то я не успеваю прочитать или даже заснять. 
Что не так? Вообще, кто-нибудь смог подключиться с Android к Azure?

Comment: какая ide?

Comment: IDE - Eclipse Juno for Mobile Developers

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что Android используется нестандартную Java машину - т.н. Dalvik VM, у которой формат байткода отличается от обычной JVM. В ходе сборки проекта после компиляции есть этап перекодирования с формата JVM в формат Dalvik VM (из .class в .dex) это производится утилитой [dx](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/index.html).

Для чего я это все рассказываю: если JDBC драйвер или вообще любая сторонняя либа используется только стандартные Java функции/классы реализованные в Android SDK - то перекодирование пройдет гладко и спокойно, а если нет - то библиотека будет недоступна и в ходе исполнения Dalvik VM выкинет исключение о том, что не найден соответствующий класс. В вашем случае это:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefError: com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext
```

Трудно ожидать, что чисто сановский класс `com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext` - был бы реализован в Android'е

**P.S.** Фактически это и есть причина [судебного процесса](http://www.tyt-gadget.ru/Articles2-Google.html) между Oracle и Google - в Android'е реализована немножко не та оригинальная Java, владельцем которой является Oracle.